# Input a number with Keypad and storing a number to EEPROM

Tags: arduino, android-keypad, eeprom, arduino-c++

Hi there I don't have very much experience in coding just a basic staff so I need help

but I need modification like:
First when user press "#" key he has to write the number which will be like a price for a product, 
Second when user press "A" key the price/number has to be stored to EEPROM memory, 
Third when user press "B" key the price/number has to be read from EEPROM memory,

when I press "*" key its working but this is not a number from memory this is just a printed number to LCD,

my problem is when I press "B" key on LCD I get some strange characters

I need code to work with EEPROM

this is my code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);  // Set the LCD I2C address
#include <Keypad.h> //include keypad library - first you must install library (library link in the video description)

const byte rows = 4; //number of the keypad's rows and columns
const byte cols = 4;

char keyMap [rows] [cols] = { //define the cymbols on the buttons of the keypad

  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

byte rowPins [rows] = {4, 5, 6, 7}; //pins of the keypad
byte colPins [cols] = {8, 9, 10, 11};

Keypad myKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keyMap), rowPins, colPins, rows, cols);


void setup() {

  // Setup size of LCD 16 characters and 2 lines
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Back light on
  lcd.backlight();
}

void loop()
{
  // user input array; 10 digits and nul character
  static char userinput[11];
  // variable to remember where in array we will store digit
  static int count = 0;
 char number;

  char key = myKeypad.getKey();

  if (key != NO_KEY)
  {

    lcd.print(key);
  }

  switch (key)
  {
    case NO_KEY:
      // nothing to do
      break;

    case '#':
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print(F("Press a number:"));
      // clear the current user input
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      memset(userinput, 0, sizeof(userinput));
      number=(userinput, 0, sizeof(userinput));
      // reset the counter
      count = 0;
      break;

    case 'A':           //Store number to memory
      EEPROM.write(0, number);
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print(F("Saved"));
      break;

    case 'B':           //Get number from memory and print to LCD
      number = EEPROM.read(0);
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print(F("Saved Number is:"));
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      lcd.println(number);//print the stored number
      break;

    case '*':
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print(F("Number:"));
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      lcd.println(userinput);//print the stored number
      break;

    default:
      // if not 10 characters yet
      if (count < 10)
      {
        // add key to userinput array and increment counter
        userinput[count++] = key;
      }
      break;
  }


  //delay(200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze your loop code:

1. The beginning of the loop looks OK. The static variables `userinput, count`will retain their value (important) and variables `count` and `number` will be zeroed with every new loop (OK).
2. In `case '#'`, you probably want to clear everything and prepare for receiving new number. Erase the `number=(userinput, 0, sizeof(userinput));` line, because that's not how you set value of a variable and because you do not want to take "#" as input number. The new entered number is saved to your `userinput` array in `default` case .
3. In `case 'A'`, you will write variable into the EEPROM. The right (basic) way how to do it is (in your case) `EEPROM.write(count, key)`. You should also put 4 ms delay after writing to EEPROM memory (it takes 3,3 ms to write a byte in an EEPROM memory). I also recommend to use function `EEPROM.update(0)`rather than `EEPROM.write(0)`. Look [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMUpdate) why. My other recommendation is to do EEPROM-writing operations after all 10 digits has been entered – you'll save some EEPROM write cycles in case user does not enter the number correctly (e.g. presses "#")...
4. In `case 'B'`, you want to read number from EEPROM. The correct implementation is

   ```
   lcd.clear();
   lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
   lcd.print(F("Saved Number is:"));
   for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
     lcd.setCursor(i, 2);
     number = EEPROM.read(i);
   lcd.println(number);//print the stored number
   }
   break;
   ```

   I haven't tested this, it is more about the idea how to do it.
5. In `case '*'`, I am not sure what you want to do – it is not clear from your decription. I think you just want to print out numbers in your `userinput`array. This can be done in similar way to `case 'B'`, so:

   ```
   lcd.clear();
   lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
   lcd.print(F("userinput no:"));
   for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
     lcd.setCursor(i, 2);
     number = userinput[i];
   lcd.println(number);
   }
   break;
   ```
6. In `case 'default'`, you are saving last entered number to the `userinput` array. This is OK.

Comment: Thank you I took your advise and now I have this problem...  because I don't know how to post it here here is a link https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=633081.0

Comment: A link to whole discussion thread is not useful, I do not know what your problem is. Learn how to post it here...

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks JSC you'v been so helpfull 
I took your advice and in the end my code should do this:
1) user enters password "###"
2) LCD shows 4 product "price List" (prices should be from EEPROM)
3) user press key "1"
4) on LCD: "please enter new price1" and the user sets some new number for "newPrice1"
5) user press key "A" and "newPrice1" is saved to EEPROM  after a small delay
on LCD there is a "PriceList" again with 4 prices but with "newPrice1"
6) user press key "2" 
7) on LCD: "please enter new price2" and the user sets some new number for new  "newPrice2"
5) user press key "A" again and "newPrice2" is saved to EEPROM after a small delay on LCD there is a "PriceList" again with 4 prices but with "newPrice2"
and so on for price3 and price4 

that is the idea :)
But my code its not working correctly and I don't know Why?
Here is the code so far

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);  // Set the LCD I2C address
#include <Keypad.h> //include keypad library - first you must install library (library link in the video description)

const byte rows = 4; //number of the keypad's rows and columns
const byte cols = 4;

char keyMap [rows] [cols] = { //define the cymbols on the buttons of the keypad

  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

byte rowPins [rows] = {4, 5, 6, 7}; //pins of the keypad
byte colPins [cols] = {8, 9, 10, 11};

Keypad myKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keyMap), rowPins, colPins, rows, cols);

// user input array; 10 digits and nul character 1234567890
static char priceArrey1[4];
static char priceArrey2[4];
static char priceArrey3[4];
static char priceArrey4[4];
// variable to remember where in array we will store digit
static int count1 = 0;
static int count2 = 0;
static int count3 = 0;
static int count4 = 0;
int newrPrice1;          //int Val za pretvoranje na od "char priceArry" vo "int number"
int newrPrice2;
int newrPrice3;
int newrPrice4;

char pressKey;
int passState = 0;
int productState = 0;


char* password = "###"; //create a password
int passLenght = 0; //keypad passLenght


void setup() {

  // Setup size of LCD 16 characters and 2 lines
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Back light on
  lcd.backlight();

}

void loop() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pressKey = myKeypad.getKey();
  if (pressKey != NO_KEY) // if any key is pressed
  {
    lcd.print(pressKey);
  }
  switch (pressKey)
  {
    case NO_KEY:
      // nothing to do if no key is pressed Blank Screen
      break;
    case '1':
      if (passState = 1) {
        productState = 1;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(F("Set New Price P1"));
        // clear the current user input
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        memset(priceArrey1, 0, sizeof(priceArrey1));
        // reset the counter
        count1 = 0;
      }
      break;
    case '2':
      if (passState = 1) {
        productState = 2;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(F("Set New Price P2"));
        // clear the current user input
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        memset(priceArrey2, 0, sizeof(priceArrey2));
        // reset the counter
        count2 = 0;
      }
      break;
    case '3':
      if (passState = 1) {
        productState = 3;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(F("Set New Price P3"));
        // clear the current user input
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        memset(priceArrey3, 0, sizeof(priceArrey3));
        // reset the counter
        count3 = 0;
      }
      break;
    case '4':
      if (passState = 1) {
        productState = 4;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(F("Set New Price P4"));
        // clear the current user input
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        memset(priceArrey4, 0, sizeof(priceArrey4));
        // reset the counter
        count4 = 0;
      }
      break;

    case 'A':           //Store number to memory
      if (passState == 1 && productState == 1) {
        newrPrice1 = atoi(priceArrey1);     // funkcioata atoi() pretvara od char to int
        EEPROM.put(0, newrPrice1);        //EEPROM.put (address, val) snima u memorijata pogolemi brojki od 255
        delay(100);                         //it takes 3,3 ms to write a byte in an EEPROM memory)
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(F("Saved P1"));
      }
      else if (passState == 1 && productState == 2) {
        newrPrice2 = atoi(priceArrey2);     // funkcioata atoi() pretvara od char to int
        EEPROM.put(3, newrPrice2);        //EEPROM.put (address, val) snima u memorijata pogolemi brojki od 255
        delay(100);                         //it takes 3,3 ms to write a byte in an EEPROM memory)
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(F("Saved P2"));
      }
      else if ((passState == 1) && (productState == 3)) {
        newrPrice3 = atoi(priceArrey3);     // funkcioata atoi() pretvara od char to int
        EEPROM.put(6, newrPrice3);        //EEPROM.put (address, val) snima u memorijata pogolemi brojki od 255
        delay(100);                         //it takes 3,3 ms to write a byte in an EEPROM memory)
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(F("Saved P3"));
      }
      else if ((passState == 1) && (productState == 4)) {
        newrPrice4 = atoi(priceArrey4);     // funkcioata atoi() pretvara od char to int
        EEPROM.put(9, newrPrice4);        //EEPROM.put (address, val) snima u memorijata pogolemi brojki od 255
        delay(100);                         //it takes 3,3 ms to write a byte in an EEPROM memory)
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(F("Saved P4"));
      }

      delay(1500);

      getSavedPrce();
      printSavedPrceLCD();           //Price List
      delay(1000);
      break;

    default:
      // if not 10 characters yet
      if (count1 < 3)
      {
        // add key to priceArrey array and increment counter
        priceArrey1[count1++] = pressKey;

      } else if (count2 < 3)
      {
        // add key to priceArrey array and increment counter
        priceArrey2[count2++] = pressKey;

      } else if (count3 < 3)
      {
        // add key to priceArrey array and increment counter
        priceArrey3[count3++] = pressKey;

      } else if (count4 < 3)
      {
        // add key to priceArrey array and increment counter
        priceArrey4[count4++] = pressKey;

      }
      break;
  }
  stateKeypad();
}

void getSavedPrce() {               //Reads savedPrice from EEPROM
  newrPrice1 = EEPROM.get(0, newrPrice1);
  delay(500);
  newrPrice2 = EEPROM.get(3, newrPrice2);
  delay(500);
  newrPrice3 = EEPROM.get(6, newrPrice3);
  delay(500);
  newrPrice4 = EEPROM.get(9, newrPrice4);
  delay(500);
}

/// Shows Price List from keypad on LCD
void printSavedPrceLCD () {                                //"Price List keypad MODE" on lcd
  lcd.clear();    //clears lcd sreen
  //1
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("P1");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
  lcd.print(newrPrice1);
  //2
  lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
  lcd.print("P2");
  lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
  lcd.print(newrPrice2);
  //3
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("P3");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 2);
  lcd.print(newrPrice3);
  //4
  lcd.setCursor(9, 2);
  lcd.print("P4");
  lcd.setCursor(12, 2);
  lcd.print(newrPrice4);
}
void stateKeypad() {      //menu password

  if (pressKey == password [passLenght]) {
    passLenght ++;

    if (passLenght == 3) {
      passState = 1;
      productState = 0;


      getSavedPrce();
      printSavedPrceLCD();           //Price List
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
}
```